# How to solve the Gammu CMS Error 38: "Network out of order"?

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, gammu

I initially went smoothly Gammu, with **status = 0 (SendingOK)** . A few minutes later i was having problems with Gammu i found:

```
Thu 2016/10/13 15:34:45 gammu-smsd[5508]: gammu: 1 "AT+CMGS=109"
Thu 2016/10/13 15:34:45 gammu-smsd[5508]: gammu: 2 "> 0691261801000011000C818031121006390000FF6CD0323BEC3E9FC36E100C179BC962B0980D969BB140EB70BB0E1297E57537BDEE3E83C86178980EB2A6C9E537680532BEE96F17085917D7DDE7F48B5A66C3DF6ED0BA0C52D56030150E661B81EA6E7A7D0D0AB7C56936685E5E87E561F7D905"
Thu 2016/10/13 15:34:45 gammu-smsd[5508]: gammu: 3 "+CMS ERROR: 38"
Thu 2016/10/13 15:34:45 gammu-smsd[5508]: gammu: Checking line: +CMS ERROR: 38
Thu 2016/10/13 15:34:45 gammu-smsd[5508]: gammu: AT reply state: 5
Thu 2016/10/13 15:34:45 gammu-smsd[5508]: gammu: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x10B/267
Thu 2016/10/13 15:34:45 gammu-smsd[5508]: gammu: Error 38
Thu 2016/10/13 15:34:45 gammu-smsd[5508]: SMS sent on device: "com11:" status=38, reference=-1
Thu 2016/10/13 15:34:45 gammu-smsd[5508]: gammu: CMS Error 38: "Network out of order"
Thu 2016/10/13 15:34:45 gammu-smsd[5508]: Error getting send status of message: Unknown error. (UNKNOWN[27])
```

and this my configuration gammu :

```
[gammu]
port = com6:
connection = at115200
[smsd]
service = sql
logfile = myphone1
debuglevel = 255
phoneid = MyPhone1
commtimeout = 1
sendtimeout = 10
checksecurity = 0
hangupcalls = 1
deliveryreport = sms
user = root
password = admin
pc = localhost
database = smsd_database
driver = native_mysql
```

I used this device **Gsm Gateway Sim Box 16 Ports Q2406B** :

```
Device : com6:
Manufacturer : Wavecom
Model : MULTIBAND 900E 1800 (MULTIBAND 900E 1800)
Firmware : 651b09gg.Q2406B 244 041410 13:45
IMEI : 354397003322627
```

I know about status 38 :

```
"Network out of order" This cause indicates that the network is not
functioning correctly and that the condition is likely to last a relatively
long period of time; e.g., immediately reattempting the short message transfer
is not likely to be successful.
```

When I turn off gammu service, and then I restart status still **gammu: CMS Error 38: "Network out of order"** How best solution to solve this problem ?

Maybe many members gammu users also have experienced the same problem and could solve it. please share here. regards.

I've been looking for with Google still has not found a solution.

I really appreciate your help

Comment: Was the networking working at that time? It might be just network outage (or outage of SMS services) causing this...

Comment: hi @MichalČihař , im used networking indonesia area, provider Telkomsel (smsc +6281100000).. This means the problem of network providers ? not in gammu service ..

Comment: Most likely. At least I don't see anything what would indicate problem in Gammu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can occur if the phone number is incorrect. For example, I had this error when I tried to text a phone number using 07********, and changing to +447***** (UK prefix) fixed this in my situation.